# Javascript array math not adding up properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, radio-button, switch-statement

I have a sequence of arrays as individual question scores, and then an array to add a score based on the scores of the questions to the main score:

```
var totscore = 0
var subscore = 0

var _scores7 = [2, 1, 0];
var _scores8 = [3, 2, 1, 0];
var _scores9 = [3, 2, 1, 0];
var _scores10 = [2, 1, 0];
var _scores11 = [1, 0];
var _scores12 = [2, 1, 0];
var _scores13 = [2, 1, 0];

var subScores = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

The questions are then supposed to add up the scores dependent upon answers on radio buttons:

```
if(document.getElementById("q7a").checked){
    subscore += _scores7[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q7b").checked){
    subscore += _scores7[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q7c").checked){
    subscore += _scores7[2];
} else alert("Question seven has not been finished.");

if(document.getElementById("q8a").checked){
    subscore += _scores8[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q8b").checked){
    subscore += _scores8[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q8c").checked){
    subscore += _scores8[2];
} else if(document.getElementById("q8d").checked){
    subscore += _scores8[3];
} else alert("Question eight has not been finished.");

if(document.getElementById("q9a").checked){
    subscore += _scores9[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q9b").checked){
    subscore += _scores9[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q9c").checked){
    subscore += _scores9[2];
} else if(document.getElementById("q9d").checked){
    subscore += _scores9[3];
} else alert("Question nine has not been finished.");

if(document.getElementById("q10a").checked){
    subscore += _scores10[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q10b").checked){
    subscore += _scores10[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q10c").checked){
    subscore += _scores10[2];
} else alert("Question ten has not been finished.");

if(document.getElementById("q11a").checked){
    subscore += _scores11[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q11b").checked){
    subscore += _scores11[1];
} else alert("Question eleven has not been finished.");

if(document.getElementById("q12a").checked){
    subscore += _scores12[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q12b").checked){
    subscore += _scores12[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q12c").checked){
    subscore += _scores12[2];
} else alert("Question twelve has not been finished.");

if(document.getElementById("q13a").checked){
    subscore += _scores13[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q13b").checked){
    subscore += _scores13[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q13c").checked){
    subscore += _scores13[2];
} else alert("Question thirteen has not been finished.");
```

The score that is received here is supposed to then be used in the following code:

```
switch(true){
    case (subscore == 0):
        totscore += subScores[6];
        break;
    case (subscore >= 1 && subscore <= 3):
        totscore += subScores[5];
        break;
    case (subscore >= 4 && subscore <= 6):
        totscore += subScores[4];
        break;
    case (subscore >= 7 && subscore <= 8):
        totscore += subScores[3];
        break;
    case (subscore >= 9 && subscore <= 11):
        totscore += subScores[2];
        break;
    case (subscore >= 12 && subscore <= 14):
        totscore += subScores[1];
        break;
    case (subscore == 15):
        totscore += subScores[0];
        break;
    default:
        alert(subscore);
```

My primary issue seems to be that the subscore addition doesn't end up where I want it to.

When you select the answers that are supposed to give you zero subscore points, you end up with six. When you answer the questions that are supposed to give you fifteen points, you get zero. If you answer down the middle, you end up with three or four.

Comment: Did you already step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: I have. On the console, there don't seem to be any syntax errors that I can find, and nothing else shows up either. I think it's written (relatively) soundly.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what you're expecting to happen.  Could you cut this down to only `subScore7` and maybe `8`?  I assume `subscore` starts at 0?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to show those. yes, subscore starts at zero. The reason that all of the questions have different arrays is that each question may have its weighting changed in the future, and I figured the easiest way to alter it would be to give each question an easily identifiable array.

Comment: My main issue is that the math doesn't add up. I don't understand that, if you select the answers associated with the highest numbers, you get six. Is there something I'm failing to understand about array math in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own mistake.

The switch statement at the end has the default set as:

```
alert(subscore)
```

There was no actual alert for subscore outside of the switch statement. So the function was actually correctly calculating totscore and I was misreading that as an alert for the subscore value.

The code is actually correct, I was looking for an error in the calculation when my error was in displaying the answer.